# Output input text to pdf file

Tags: php

Im using FPDF and FPDI libraries to edit pdf file. I created html text and submit input. I would like to take text input from html code and output it into pdf file. This is my code:
HTML:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="post_text" id="post_text">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
..
$text = $_POST['post_text'];
...

$pdf->Write(0,'$text');
...
```

Then I write anything like `hello, this is me` in the textbox and I'm getting `$text` value output to my pdf. But I want that output to be the text written in textbox?

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes near $text?
$pdf->Write(0,$text);

Comment: `$text` is a variable, you don't need to adding quotes. that is for only a string.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing `$text` as text, you don't need quotes if you want to print the variable contents.

```
$pdf->Write(0, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning constant string value to PDF write,

```
$pdf->Write(0, '$text');
```

it takes `$text` as a string.

try with:

```
$pdf->Write(0, $text);
```

It will write whatever content in $text onto pdf!